# How select Text in TextBock?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I only found a way to:

```
<TextBox Text="Text!" 
IsReadOnly="True" 
IsTabStop="False" 
BorderThickness="0"
>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
                        <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="False" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

There is another option not so big?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gishu has the right idea.

Use a TextBox and make it ReadOnly.  The user can select and copy the text, but cannot alter the text.

```
    <TextBox IsReadOnly='True'  Text='ABC ABD ABC ABD'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a TextBox if you want it to be interactive ?
TextBlocks should be used to display static text -- its a light weight variant of the WPF Label.

Comment: I need that would be interactive, just that you could select and copy.
Label, too, does not release the text

Comment: @simply, if you need to be able to right click and copy text, I think you should use a textbox. If you do not want the user to change the text, set its readonly prop to true.